# Dynamically return fields from a web method

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a WebAPI service where I would like to allow users to specify which fields they'd like returned. For example, say I have the following `Person` class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

and that calling `/api/people/` returns all three fields for all people. How do I handle a request like `/api/people?fields=FirstName,Email` returning just those two fields for all people? Bonus points if I can map something like `first_name` to `FirstName` but that's not required.

Comment: I believe you are looking for [OData](https://dotnetthoughts.net/getting-started-with-odata-in-aspnet-core/)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto correct me if I'm wrong but I think OData is in alpha stage right?

Comment: @EdwardChopuryan It could be, haven't really used that for ASP.NET Core

Comment: It looks like OData has the functionality via the `$select` property however Core support is spotty at best.

Comment: @PhillipCopley yep it is in alpha stage. If it bothers you you have to write your own controller. It shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: I wanted to do a similar thing a few months ago. OData was an option but I (and our front end guy) didn't fancy ending up bald by I was 30. I prototyped a custom model binder which matched properties from `_fields` key in the query and allowed this to flow through to a linq select query -- ending up in only desired fields being sent to the client. In the end I scrapped it all, accepted the overhead of serialising and sending potentially-unnecessary fields and put my models on a diet. It was too much complexity for little reward. What's a few bytes between friends, eh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for the [Dynamic Language Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/dynamic-language-runtime-overview) and specifically [`ExpandoObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx), whereby you return only the properties you need *as determined at runtime*:

```
public dynamic GetPerson()
{
    bool firstNameRequired = true; // TODO: Parse querystring
    bool lastNameRequired = false; // TODO: Parse querystring

    dynamic rtn = new ExpandoObject();

    if (firstNameRequired)
        rtn.first_name = "Steve";

    if (lastNameRequired)
        rtn.last_name = "Jobs";

    // ... and so on

    return rtn;
}

void Main()
{
    // Using the serializer of your choice:
    Console.WriteLine(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GetPerson()));
}
```

Output:

> {"first_name":"Steve"}

I don't have the means to test it right now [I have something similar in production on vanilla Web API, with a large number of optional fields], but going by the .NET Core docs the web method would look something like this albeit without the hard coded values!:

```
[HttpGet()]
public IActionResult Get([FromQuery(Name = "fields")] string fields)
{
    var fieldsOptions = fields.Split(',');

    dynamic rtn = new ExpandoObject();

    if (fieldsOptions.Contains("FirstName"))
        rtn.first_name = "Steve";

    if (fieldsOptions.Contains("LastName"))
        rtn.last_name = "Jobs";

    if (fieldsOptions.Contains("Email"))
        rtn.email = "steve@apple.com";

    return new ObjectResult(rtn);
}
```

---

You would need to reference the [System.Dynamic.Runtime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Dynamic.Runtime/) package.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [conditional serialization](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm). You will just base your ShouldSerialize return value on whether or not the fields parameter contains the string identifying that field. This will work for whatever string(s) you want to associate with the field. You can even accept multiple strings for each field, if you want to.

To get the fieldList into the object you want to serialize (Person), you can just pass it or something that contains it (HttpRequest.Query or some custom Options class) into the constructor.

```
public bool ShouldSerializeFirstName(){  
    return fieldList.Contains("FirstName");            
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this tightly couple you to NewtonSoft's json serialiser? How would you go about injecting the field list from the query string?

Comment: But yes, if you wanted this to work with a custom serlializer, it would have to support conditional serialization consistent with Json.NET .

Comment: This is a neat concept and I'm hovering over the +1 button, but you don't appear to have answered @Mardoxx 's question "How would you go about injecting the field list from the query string?".  It looks like `ShouldSerializeFirstName` would need to be defined in the `Person` class, and therefore you'd have to use the static `HttpContext.Current` property in order to get the request details. I'm not sure I like having that dependency in my domain objects unless they're strictly web facing only. At the very least, if my assessment is correct, you should return true if HttpContext.Current is null

Comment: I'm not seeing anywhere that he says Person is a domain object. And I think how to decouple a WebApi DTO from from a domain object is outside the scope of this question. If he does have that need, creating a wrapper in the application layer PersonDTO with the serialization members on it would be a simple solution. The wrapper could just pass through common data from the Person object get{return base.FirstName;}, etc

Comment: @StephenKennedy I've address some of your concerns in an edit.