# How to define anonymous object property dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm making a small application in my website to get user information using API request.

```
[HttpGet("GetUserInfo/{user_id}/{fields?}")]
public IActionResult GetUserInfo(string user_id, params string[] fields)
{
    var userProfile = _userManager.GetUserProfile(user_id);

    if (userProfile == null)
    {
        return Ok(null);
    }

    var userInfo = new
    {
        id = userProfile.UserId,
        email = userProfile.Email,
        name = userProfile.Name,
        // I don't want to define a null property here:
        picture_url = fields.Contains("picture_url") ? "path" : null
    };

    if (fields.Contains("picture_url"))
    {
        userInfo.picture_url = "";
    }

    return Ok(userInfo);
}
```

When a request is valid, it returns a JSON object which contains 3 properties by default: `id`, `email`, and `name`.

Now, I want to check that if the request want to get more information about this user, just like `picture_url`. So, I've tried:

```
if (fields.Contains("picture_url"))
{
    // error in this line
    userInfo.picture_url = "path";
}
```

> '<anonymous type: string id, string email, string name>' does not contain a definition for 'picture_url' and no extension method 'picture_url' accepting a first argument of type '<anonymous type: string id, string email, string name>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I add some property to an anonymous object dynamically?

Comment: Anonymous types are immutable, you can only set the property when creating the instance.

Comment: use `dynamic` instead of `var`

Comment: @SebastianHofmann `dynamic` is almost never the right choice, and almost always a sticking plaster over a gaping wound.

Comment: True, but it would do what OP wants. Of course it would be better to just set the `null`. Plus, that makes the code more readable.

Comment: @SebastianHofmann But OP doesn't want the null property, that's the entire point of the question. It's quite simple to do and still readable with my answer.

Comment: `dynamic` is almost always the right choice when dynamically adding properties to an object which will be consumed by a dynamic language such as JavaScript...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically return fields from a web method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48686726/dynamically-return-fields-from-a-web-method)

Comment: @StephenKennedy I disagree, I'd rather go with a `Dictionary`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Anonymous types are immutable, you can only create and set properties when creating the instance. This means you need to create the exact object you need. So you could do something like this instead:

```
if (fields.Contains("picture_url"))
{
    return Ok(new
    {
        id = userProfile.UserId,
        email = userProfile.Email,
        name = userProfile.Name,
        picture_url = "path"
    });
}

return Ok(new
{
    id = userProfile.UserId,
    email = userProfile.Email,
    name = userProfile.Name
});
```

Another option is to used a `Dictionary<string, object>`. For example:

```
var userInfo = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"id", userProfile.UserId},
    {"email", userProfile.Email},
    {"name", userProfile.Name}
};

if (fields.Contains("picture_url"))
{
    // error in this line
    userInfo.Add("picture_url", "path");
}

return Ok(userInfo);
```

This object will serialise to the same JSON structure:

```
{"id":1,"email":"email@somewhere.com","name":"Bob","picture_url":"path"}
```

Comment: Same for me, anonymous types are useful, but only in certain situations.

Comment: Second example probably ignores any casing formatter.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Yes, it will use the casing of the string in the dictionary key.

Answer (score 3):

You can cast the object to dynamic and add the property or use the `ExpandoObject` class, which is basically a property bag (which implements as  `IDictionary<string, object>`).

```
var userInfo = new
{
    id = userProfile.UserId,
    email = userProfile.Email,
    name = userProfile.Name
};

dynamic result = userInfo;

if (fields.Contains("picture_url"))
{
    result.picture_url = "<your url here>";

    // alternatively use expando object
    // var expando =  (IDictionary<String, Object>)result;
    // expando.Add("picture_url", "<your url here>");
    // the first parameter is the name of the property
}

return result;
```

Beware though, that using `dynamic` keyword or `ExpandoObject` you lose strong typed and Intellisense support.

But it will allow you to add or remove properties from the final json response.

#### Edit

Also see my answer on the similar question [Filtering Out Properties in an ASP.NET Core API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369970/filtering-out-properties-in-an-asp-net-core-api/36373030#36373030)
.

While you need be careful when using `dynamic`/`ExandoObject` for your use case or a graphapi-similar features it should work well fine. For removing properties you'd just use the `exanod.Remove("PropertyName")` method.

Also filtering could be implemented as easy as

```
var dictionaryResult = expando.Where(kv => filter.Contains(kv.Key))
    .ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
```

This removes all properties which are not defined in the `filter` string array. And it works with any type, `annonymous` or strong typed.

Comment: I have only 1 trouble while using `dynamic` object: `Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type.` In this case, Linq is useless here.

Comment: You cast it to dynamic **outside** of the Linq lambda's (i.e. casting your anonymous class to dynamic).Lambdas only work with strong typing and anonymous classes are strong types, they are just given a random name by the compiler when compiling it.

Comment: Right! But what if I have multiple statements that need to cast? Ex: I want to use Linq with `connection_id`, `picture_url`, `status`, `address`.... Casting 1 or 2 times is okay, I can do that, but 3 or 4 times more will make the code become hard to read (just avoid).

Comment: You fetch all the data you need into **ONE** object, then cast it and remove whatever you don't need. See the example above, you put everything you need into `userInfo`, then remove what the user doesn't want. If you really want to reduce the data fetched form database you will have to do it the *hard way* by building Expression trees and pass these into the lambda. But its a non-trivial task to dynamically create such an expression tree

Comment: Have a read at [Dixon's post on EF Core](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/entity-framework-core-and-linq-to-entities-5-query-translation-implementation) if you want to get an idea how expression trees work

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I'm still reading the doc. I will keep it in mind for the next time. Thank you!

Comment: In which .Net version is the first example with var/dynamic working? It fails for me at runtime. Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''<>f__AnonymousType0<string,string,string>' does not contain a definition for 'picture_url''